# How can i get "https://artists.youtube.com/charts/tracks?hl=tr " this page source code with C#?

Tags: youtube, httpwebrequest, webclient

I use this code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://artists.youtube.com/charts/tracks?hl=tr");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But I cant get source code. Everytime I get this error:

> Your browser isn't supported :( YouTube ArtistHub requires a browser which supports modern web standards.

How can I get this page's source code?

Answer (score 0):

Hell pal, 
I would do this in [webclient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than webrequest.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient;
String source = wc.DownloadString(URL)
```

The variable source should have the source code for the page

Comment: still continue same situation.i get this  Your browser isn't supported :( YouTube ArtistHub requires a browser which supports modern web standards.